# How to log environment which Rails is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I tried using

```
logger.info "Rails Environment #{RAILS.env}"
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::RAILS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Rails.env` instead of `RAILS.env`. So, that would be

```
logger.info "Rails Environment #{Rails.env}"
```

Rails interpretes `RAILS` as a constant. That is why there's an 'uninitialized constant' error.

I remember deprecation warnings when using `RAILS_ROOT` or `RAILS_ENV`. Then they got yanked (no idea which version). Now, these are interpreted as constants. So, `Rails.root` and `Rails.env` are used instead - new ones are available in both Rails 2 and 3.

May be you confused `RAILS.env` with `RAILS_ENV`. But, none of these two function now.